# How to Skip ReadOnly and Disabled inputs while using .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would this code be modified so it does not `.focus()` the first form object if it is `readonly` or `disabled` and to skip to the next form input for focus?

Currently it returns an error if the first input box is disabled, but i would also like to skip to the next input box if it's readonly too, and if all inputs are disabled and readonly, then it should not focus anything..

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Focus first element
    $.fn.focus_first = function() {
      var elem = $('input:visible', this).get(0);
      var select = $('select:visible', this).get(0);
      if (select && elem) {
        if (select.offsetTop < elem.offsetTop) {
          elem = select;
        }
      }
      var textarea = $('textarea:visible', this).get(0);
      if (textarea && elem) {
        if (textarea.offsetTop < elem.offsetTop) {
          elem = textarea;
        }
      }

      if (elem) {
        elem.focus();
      }
      return this;
    }
    </script>
```

Actually using `input:enabled:visible` fixes alot of my issues, but i'm still trying to figure out if readonly, to skip to the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is the answer anyways for those looking..

```
 var elem = $('input:enabled:visible:not([readonly="readonly"])', this).get(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
$(yourElement).not(":disabled").not(":readonly")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the condition to

```
if (elem && !elem.prop('readonly') && !elem.prop('disable')) {
```